# How to delete broken/dead links in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: php, joomla, seo, broken-links

I'm working on an old project based on `Joomla 1.5`. Most of its code was written in core php but it does have SEO URLs. I'm required remove dead links (about 2000 URLs) from the site as it is lowering our organic reach.

When I opened each of them, they showed me the `404 Error page` of the site. I couldn't figure out what was wrong with that. After all, that's why we have `404 pages`, right? .. to display errors when a link is not found over our server, right?

I tried cleaning up Server's Cache and even purging expired cache after reading some tuts. Now that it doesn't seem to help, I'm not sure what to do! So, any helps?
Btw, site is at [www.parentune.com](http://www.parentune.com)
and an example dead link is: http://www.parentune.com/parenting-blog/category/Adoption/latest

Comment: How about redirect the 404 to the joomla page-not-found in htaccess? There were extensions out there for this but I think you won't find any for 1.5

Comment: Everything is fine with 404 error page as it does show up with the regular design. But they (SEO) want the dead links be removed. I want to know what needs to be done.

Comment: I think you'll need to scan your page for these links (there are tools for this) and request to remove the links from the search engines (each has its own process to do that, google/bing/yahoo etc.)

Comment: I did scan them and got a list of about 50 links. Still, the problem is, how to remove something which doesn't even exist!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't have any new URLs to redirect those old URLs to, but had the list of those reported URLs in an excel file, so what I did is I read the Excel file in an array and matched if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` was in that array (obviously, all the URLs in that array have to be relative to index page). If the  URL was found in the array, I simply redirected the page to homepage.
I also cross checked then on [brokenlinkcheck.com](http://brokenlinkcheck.com) and then it didn't report those URLs again as 404 URLs. So, seems like the approach fitted as solution! `:D`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have something to remove as it doesn't exist in your site.

You have to create 301 redirects for old url to new to help search engine crawl your updated content.

A 301 redirect example is:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html /newpage.html
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Did you mean I'll have to create  a mapping for each of those URLs, which is about 2000 in count? `:O` `:/`

Comment: If you don't want to make them one by one you have ether to find a htaccess pattern that will help you categorize them or redirect 404 page to your index that is not suggested.

Comment: There has got to be some way. I cannot do this manually for about 2000 links! `:(`